# Deepin Linux installed, ugly and unresponsive GRUB menu

Tags: boot, grub, deepin

I bought a small, used laptop (Lenovo Thinkpad X1 Carbon, 3rd gen.), mainly to take it with me on trips, to make office stuff and code ;-) So i thought, not another windows, let's try a Linux distro again. I've had Ubuntu, Mint etc. for a couple of times in the past. This time I choose Deepin Linux for it's nice look and the simplicity.

Since over a day I tried the installation, every time there where some hickups, like ACPI Errors ("Needed type [Reference], found [Integer]" or "Method parse/execution failed"), or USB errors (error -110). But in the end somehow I managed to run it.

The only thing thats very ugly is the GRUB menu, it's graphical disorted und doesn't seem to take the keyboard inputs correct. For better understanding, I've attached a pic.
I've tried to change the resolution in grub.cfg, but that doesn't change a thing.
Does anyone can tell me how I get a nice, normal GRUB menu?
Also, while booting, there are some short messsages, like the one with the ACPI error, is it possible to hide them and only show the graphic while booting?

Just to be sure, another thing: It's possible to move the /home mount point to a extra partition and crypt it after first install, right?

[image]

Comment: Use the default textmode menu, forget gfxmenu.

Comment: Thaks, i would love to do so, how can I accomplish this?

Comment: Simply doesn't load the gfxmenu module in `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` and don't change videomode.

Answer (score 1):

After changeing the resolution you need to:

```
update-grub
```

You can also turn off acpi in the grub configuration:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi=off"
```

As far as making the grub menu look better you could try setting the

```
GFXMODE="1024x768" or to the best resolution your monitor supports.
```

To answer the last question, yes you can migrate the home folder and crypt it. You will just have to edit the fstab to reflect the changes.